# Too many timeouts in android?

Tags: android

i have an Http client in my android app that changes messages with a server.
lately 2 out of every 3 ( approx) messages i send to the server get timed out
is that normal?
Thanks in advance!
Omri

Comment: What's your reception like? It's normal to get timeouts when you've bad reception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try finding the source for the timeout.
It's definitely not normal to get a timeout on a simple request/response.
Did you try timing how long it takes for the request to reach your server?
How long does it take it for your server to issue the response?
How long does it take for the client to receive this response?

You can add print outs to the server and client after syncing their clocks, showing the time of each of these steps.
Then find the problem in your code (probably) that causes these delays.